# Python Regular Expression issue r'\/([^]]*)\ '

Tags: python

```
import re

path = "xyz pqr /all_it_abc type = cell"
s = re.findall(r'\/([^]*)\ ', path)
```

is giving me error "return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string"

```
s= re.findall(r'\/([^]]*)\ ', path)
```

is giving me output as `['all_it_abc type =']`

why? I have to use "]]"

```
print(s)
```

Desired output is all_it_abc

Thanks in advance to all and stackoverflow

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Please see [ask] and fix your formatting.

Comment: desired output is all_it_abc

Answer (score 0):

In regex the pattern

```
pattern = r'[^abcd]'
```

means that this position can be matched by *anything BUT*  `'a'`, `'b'` ,`'c'` or `'d'`.

```
pattern = r'[^]'
```

is an incomplete pattern that could match anything BUT `']'` - if you complete it to a valid `r[^]]` pattern by closing the bracket.

You need  `r'/([^ ]+)`:

```
import re

path = "xyz pqr /all_it_abc type = cell"
s = re.findall(r'/([^ ]+)', path) # find all after / thats not a space

print(type(s), s) # this is a list of all matches
```

To get a list of all matches:

```
(<type 'list'>, ['all_it_abc'])
```

Comment: Also there is no need for \  before `/` - `/` is in no way special in regexps.

Comment: @Blo yep - and the \ before the space is also not needed: copy&paste error of his regex - its not needed at all because its already in `'[^ ]+'` - thanks for seeing / mentioning

Answer (score 0):

The regex your are trying to find is  is capturing a group `[^]]` This represents any character except ']'. That's why you are getting undesired output.

Your expected output can be obtained by using this simple regex instead.

```
s = re.findall(r'\/([a-z_]*)', path)
```

where s gives you this list as output

```
['all_it_abc']
```

Explanation - it captures everything after the slash that has an underscore or alphabet in it. You can add more characters to include them in the captured group.

```
r'\/([a-z_]*)'
```